# How to fix this "syntax error" in Razor?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have code like this in my Razor view

```
<script>
    var JsModel = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(CsModel));
</script>
```

This *works* just fine. It converts the C# model received from the controller to a JS object, which is later used to populate Google Map with markers and various other stuff.

The problem is, Visual Studio is showing a big red syntax error in this line, and it's driving me insane. The code is perfectly fine, model is always non-null, and the encoding always works. But Razor parser, or perhaps even R#, I'm not sure which, trips up on it, as it seems to ignore C# code. So what it sees is just `var JsModel = ;` and complains.

Any way for me to tell it that it's ok? What can I do here?

Comment: btw from your picture you remind me of one of indian actor see the link http://mtv.in.com/photos/splitsvilla-7/splitsvilla-7-rishabh-sinha-50007325.html :P

Comment: hehe :) yes from your picture you look a bit like him

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can get around this by putting raw json into quotes, and thus tricking the parser, and then using JQuery eval (or any other eval you prefer) to convert string into an object.

```
<script>
    var JsModel = $.parseJSON('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(CsModel))');
</script>
```

Comment: Do you *need* that `@Html.Raw` in there?

Comment: Yes, without it you get `{&quot;count&quot;: 15}` instead of `{"count": 15}` which breaks everything.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
  var JsModel = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(CsModel))';  //apply single quotes as shown
</script>
```

Comment: Hmm, that just makes it into a string. Shouldn't there be some sort of eval to convert that string into a JS object in there?

Comment: @Davor..there will be not change in functionality when you use single quotes its just a syntax issue..

Comment: No, it changes syntax from something like `var json = {"count": 15};`, which evaluates JSON into an object immidiately, into `var json = '{"count": 15}'; `, which creates a string variable containing json that needs to be evaluated. While it doesn't work, your answer gave me an idea how to solve the problem, so definitely +1.

Comment: you can use ``JSON.parse()``

Comment: @EhsanSajjad - yes, I just solved it that way, and posted it as an answer. And immediately got downvoted. People...

Answer (score 1):

Use function as shown below :

```
function SetMyValue(value){
    return value;
}

var JsModel = SetMyValue(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(CsModel)));
```

As documented here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740(v=vs.118).aspx:-

> This method wraps HTML markup using the IHtmlString class, which
>   renders unencoded HTML.

The Razor escaping system will not escape anything of type IHtmlString. The Html.Raw() method simply returns an HtmlString instance containing your text.

So wrapping it into function and returning from there would work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I managed to solve it in one line without making additional functions (which really bugged me), so I can't accept this as answer, but I learned something useful, plus, it works and solves the problem, so definitely +1.